# Why I lost my connection after configurating my own network?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox, internet

I have to create my own network between three virtual machines. One would be the machine that will act as the host and the rest will be connected to it.

The three virtual machines that I have to connect are:

- Windows Server 2008 (host)
- Windows 7
- Ubuntu 14.04

I was able to connect Windows 7 virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 and have connection to Internet in both of them but I am getting troubles with the last one.

I have to use the following configuration:

```
                  Windows 7            Ubuntu            Windows Server

IP               192.168.1.3         192.168.1.4         192.168.1.5
Subnet mask      255.255.255.0       255.255.255.0       255.255.255.0
Gateway          192.168.1.1         192.168.1.1         192.168.1.1
Main DNS         192.168.1.5         192.168.1.5         127.0.0.1
Secondary DNS      8.8.8.8             8.8.8.8             8.8.8.8
```

On Ubuntu virtual machine is where I am getting problems so I am going to describe the process that I use to configure the network on it.

I have used the following command to configure the interface:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and I have edited the file as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.5 8.8.8.8
```

And I tried to restart the network to save the changes with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

but I am getting the following error:

> stop: Job failed while stopping
>
> start: Job is already running: networking

I thought that the problem was here because it gave to me that error but if I use the command `ifconfig` I am getting the configuration that I have already configurated.

I do not have access to Internet, though.

Am I missing some configuration? Am I configurating my network in the wrong way?

**EDIT:** This is the output when I use `ifconfig eth0`:

```
Direc. inet: 192.168.1.4 Difus: 192.168.1.255  Masc: 255.255.255.0
....................................
Packages RX:535 errors: 0 lost: 0 overruns: 0 frame: 0
Packages TX:87 errors: 0 lost: 0 overruns: 0 carrier: 0
colisions: 0 long.colaTX: 1000
Bytes RX: 41785 (41.7 KB)   TX bytes: 10286 (10.2 KB)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To restart the network, use `sudo service network-manager restart`. Also please post the output of `ifconfig eth0`

Comment: @hamiheim I have used both commands and I have edited my question with the output of `ifconfig eth0`.

Comment: And you got the same error both times? No change after system reboot?

Comment: @hamiheim What do you mean? I have used `sudo service network-manager restart` and I did not have any error there. After that I reboot the virtual machine but I still do not have connection to Internet

Comment: Does your Hyper Visor see the IP of that VM as `192.168.1.4`?

Comment: @hamiheim I am so new at networks configuration so I do not understand what do you mean with Hyper Visor. Tell me as a totally beginner please.

Comment: The Hyper Visor is the application that you are using to host your VMs, since you're using WinServer 2008 I'm assuming you're using Hyper V but it could be VirtualBox or any number of Virtualization Software

Comment: @hamiheim Oh, I am using VirtualBox to host my VMs. How can I know if it see the IP?

Comment: In VirtualBox when you've highlighted the VM on the left, make sure the details button is selected on the right. You should see detailed information about the VM including System, Display, Audio and Network. 
Please refer to the following [Techmint article](http://www.tecmint.com/network-between-guest-vm-and-host-virtualbox/) and ensure you have setup the network adapter correctly.

Comment: I have there three VMs at the same adapter 1 and they are of type: `Intel PRO/ 1000 MT Desktop (82540 EM)`. As it is a homework task I do not think I have to configure any extra networks or something like that. I only have the specifications that I have put on my question and that I had to use this kind of adapter.

Comment: Please post the output of the following `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c 3 google.com`

Comment: @hamiheim It gives to me `3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms`.

Comment: It gives you that for both?

Comment: @hamiheim Oh, no, sorry. It only gives to me on the first one. It gives to me `ping: unknown host google.com` on the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with DNS resolution. Change your interfaces file to reflect the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameserver 192.168.1.5 8.8.8.8
```

Then run `sudo service network-manager restart` to reload interface with updated nameserver. You should have internet access.

Comment: Now I have connection to Internet. Thank you very much! Just as a note: you set a typo in your answer `manager` and that I had to reboot the VM after doing the changes and restarting the network. Thanks again!